# Передник или фартук?

Tags: семантика

Прошу помощи в сложном вопросе.
В Википедии и прочих справочниках не делается различия между двумя этими понятиями - передник и фартук. Это просто кусок материи, защищающий переднюю часть тела.
Но такие предметы одежды бывают двух видов: один - защищающий грудь, и второй - доходящий только до пояса. Какой из этих предметов может с большим правом называться передник, а какой - фартук? Вопрос не праздный. Речь идёт о старинном скандинавском народном костюме, в котором применялся передник, который крепился только на пояс, не закрывая груди. В шведском варианте - förkläde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В значении "предмет одежды" это очень близкие слова. Но различить все-таки можно.

Я не буду вдаваться в профессиональные заморочки дизайнеров и костюмеров, попытаюсь своими словами.

У *"фартука"*, помимо "детали одежды", есть масса других значений в технике, объединенных смыслом "устройство или деталь для защиты от внешних воздействий". С таким же смыслом обычно используется и как предмет гардероба: защищающая от грязи одежда.

У "передника" такого ассоциативного ряда нет. Есть правда, другой, это может быть любой "передний", встроенный или самостоятельный, элемент одежды и не только, другими словами - некий "передок".  Но это не столь нежелательная ассоциация, все-таки смысл подходящ.

Так что я за ***"передник"*** как деталь костюма.

А насколько существенно дать именно точную характеристику предмета? Все равно, как ни назови, без расшифровки ни у кого не будет ясности, что это именно поясной элемент одеяния?!

Comment: Спасибо! Мне близки эти мысли. Говоря кратко: слово "фартук" звучит более профессионально; "передник" - имеет более повседневный, народный, более простой смысл. Наверно это определяет то, что "фартук" - иностранное слово, а "передник" - отечественное.

Answer (score 2):

Слова передник и фартук имеют одинаковое значение.

[Словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/926018):

> ПЕРЕ́ДНИК, передника, муж.
>   1. Одежда разного покроя, надеваемая на переднюю часть туловища, преим. для предохранения платья, костюма от загрязнения, то же, что фартук. Кухарка в ситцевом переднике. Кожаный передник (напр. у кузнеца). Детский передник. Нарядный передник.

[Словарь Ожегова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/256490):

> ФА́РТУК, -а, муж.
>   1. То же, что передник.

(У обоих слова есть еще техническое значение.)
Передник (фартук), доходящий только до пояса, называется «передник на поясе» или «поясной».
Фартук(передник), защищающий грудь, называется «передник с нагрудником» или «нагрудный». Последний термин может относиться как детали одежды для взрослых, так и к детской одежде типа «слюнявчик».
Еще бывает передник-туника, передник с рукавами, передник с отдельными нарукавниками и еще много разных передников.

Какое слово лучше использовать в вашем случае?
Когда идет речь о русской народной одежде, чаще используется слово «передник». Но с другой стороны, слово «фартук» — иностранного происхождения,  поэтому, мне кажется, в тексте про скандинавский костюм больше подойдет «фартук».

Comment: Повторю то, что писал Галине - в моём "мире" существуют "фартуки", как рабочая одежда (благодаря behemothus мне удалось всё-таки определиться), и передник - как обязательная деталь женской одежды. Думаю, что некоторые исторические факты говорят о том, что передник в древней истории был знаком перехода человека в стадию половой зрелости. Позже - знаком плодородия. И только уже ближе к развитию металлургии в промышленных масштабах - обрёл верхнюю часть и стал принадлежностью профессиональной деятельности.

Comment: Видимо, не дошло. что ФА́РТУК, -а, муж.
1. То же, что передник.

Answer (score 2):

> Иногда фартук дополнен "грудкой", которая пришивается к поясу и
>   бретелям...

И ничего не поделаешь, в русском это синонимы; фартук от немцев, передник  - "искон."

> ...Итак передники. Так было давно, так продолжается и доселе, что
>   многие путают передники с фартуками. А отличие такое простое: фартуки
>   — это те, что с «грудкой», а передники без.

[Приведённое рассуждение](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.577618208917762.1073741826.279237792089140&type=3) для меня неубедительно.

Если вопрос принципиальный, выходите из положения "описательно".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [изображения](http://www.hannakaffepanna.se/forkladen).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы написала: передник с грудкой на бретелях с оборками.

Comment: Спасибо. По тексту - моя героиня носит народную одежду Скандинавии 16-17 века. В комплект этой одежды до сих пор входит  förkläde без "грудки", с узорчатым поясом с кисточками и большим кошелем (сумкой) на поясе. То, что на вашей картинке - это отголосок французской моды. В моём "мире" нет Франции как таковой. :) (Прошу прощения у французов). Но и фартуки есть! Ещё раз, спасибо.